# SQLite Database Error: No Table Found Android

Tags: java, android, database

I get this error when trying to create a database:
error message 
    enter code here
    02-23 02:08:46.780: E/Database(32721): Error 
    inserting email=af contact=38  dob=1/8/68    name=ex
    02-23 02:08:46.780: E/Database(32721):
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
     profiles: , while   compiling:      INSERT INTO profiles
     (email, contact, dob, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
    02-23 02:08:46.780:  E/Database(32721):
    atandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    02-23 02:08:46.780: E/Database(32721):  at

```
package a.vaccination;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class datahandler {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_name = "name";
public static final String KEY_dob = "dob";
public static final String KEY_contact = "contact";
public static final String KEY_email = "email";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "profile";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "profiles";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE
 = "create table  (id integer primary      keyautoincrement, "
 + "name VARCHAR not null, dob date, contact VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);";
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public datahandler(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            //db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old   data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    }

// ---opens the database---
public datahandler open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

// ---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String name, String dob, String contact,
        String email) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_name, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_dob, dob);
    initialValues.put(KEY_contact, contact);
    initialValues.put(KEY_email, email);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// ---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String name, String dob,
        String contact, String email) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_name, name);
    args.put(KEY_dob, dob);
    args.put(KEY_contact, contact);
    args.put(KEY_email, email);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

Comment: also attach my database file :

Comment: @Saurabh, Please put your best effort into posting clean questions with good formatting and your best knowledge of English. I fixed your question for now. Also, as 323go says, post some code.

Comment: thanks for comment ,i post my database file pl z check that ,because some my fault error code doesn't look well thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrent:

- You are missing tablename
- You are missing space between key and autoincrement

So correct it following:

```
String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table TableName(id integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ "name VARCHAR not null, dob date, contact VARCHAR, email VARCHAR)";
```

Now it will work.

Comment: @ sajmon_d Thanks for help,but i still facing error02-24 23:56:04.939: E/Database(8203): Error inserting email= contact= dob= name=

Comment: add here full logcat and Java code where you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with a table name here

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE
 = "create table TABLENAME (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
 + "name VARCHAR not null, dob date, contact VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);";
```

This looks like a reason behind

> no such table: profiles

Comment: @ sajmon_d and @ mayukh R Thanks for help,but i still facing error02-24 23:56:04.939: E/Database(8203): Error inserting email= contact= dob= name=